# Load on a server is high using Nginx

Tags: nginx-location

I have a server which continuously sends http requests to a Nginx server. Nginx will upstream it to 4 servers. But i am seeing a problem where load balancing is not working well as one particular server receives 50% of requests. My nginx config has below.

```
upstream cmdc {
    server cmdc2b:5600 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server cmdc2a:5600 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server cmdc1d:5600 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server cmdc1c:5600 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    keepalive 30;
}
```

Can someone help me here? Does any other parameter affects this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Marcin How can this be an off-topic? There were several queries asked on Nginx here.

Comment: this question hardly an offtopic due to [26K questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx) with _nginx_ tag, however the question is not clear at all. Without enough details (configuration, logs) this question may be closed

Comment: I'd say that if anything, this belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) rather than the Unix Stack Exchange.